# Javascript (no JQuery) function that retrieves JSON objects from different URLs?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I've been looking for an AJAX function that receives an URL and then returns the JSON object.

Let's say I need to display some Users info from a JSON in URL1 and also mix that display with some Posts info from a JSON in URL2.

I'll like to do this without JQquery.

Let's say something like this:

```
function loadJSON(path, success, error)
{
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
{
    if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
        if (xhr.status === 200) {
            if (success)
                success(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));

        } else {
            if (error)
                error(xhr);
        }
    }
};
xhr.open("GET", path, true);
xhr.send();
}

function getInfo(){
var users, posts;
loadJSON('http://.com/users',
         function(dataU) {
            users = dataU;
         },
         function(xhr) { console.error(xhr); }
);
loadJSON('http://.com/posts',
         function(dataP) {
            posts = dataP;
         },
         function(xhr) { console.error(xhr); }
);

console.log(users);
console.log(posts);

}

getInfo();
```

Comment: *"I've been* looking *for an AJAX function"* - Have you tried *writing* an Ajax function? Are the URLs in question from different domains? Note that in general Ajax is *asynchronous*, so an Ajax function wouldn't return the results directly, it would return them via a callback function or promise.

Comment: There are quite a few nuances working with the XMLHttpRequest object and browser inconsistencies. A library that encapsulates it will make your life easier. There are plenty of examples out the on using the XMLHttpRequest object.

Comment: You have your console.logs in the wrong place. They need to be inside the loadJSON callbacks

Comment: What is your question? Does your code not work?

Comment: @torazaburo Actually it doesn't work it is a guide of what I'm trying to do, but I recognize it's no helping. 
In short I need to display all USERNAME from a USERS JSON in URL1, but right next to the name I have to display how many posts this user posted by a USERID in a POSTS JSON located in URL2.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this without jQuery, you can fall back to plain JavaScript `XMLHttpRequest`s. This will allow you to establish an HTTP connection with a remote host and e.g. `GET` data.

To get started with those requests, you can have a look at [MDN's getting started guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started).

The [`JSON.parse()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) will help you convert the JSON string into a JavaScript object.

---

As an alternative to `XMLHttpRequest`s, you can also look into the [`fetch` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API). It provides a cleaner interface for HTTP calls. Since it is still experimental however, you may want to use a polyfill.

Answer (score -1):

With or without `jQuery` the `XMLHttpRequest` objest **is** asynchronous. jQuery uses it internally. *FIY* AJAX stands for **A**synchronous **J**avascript **A**nd **X**ml. It means that you **cannot** receive a **synchronous** result from an **asynchronous** function. But you can and should use the result in a **callback** function you send to the request.
So *correct* usage is to call `console.log` (or whatever you want) from `success` or `error` callbacks.
There are known solution how to `degrade gracefully` when `XMLHttpRequest` is not available. Among these solutions are create and append `script` or `iframe` and then read from their `.onload` handlers. All of them are **asynchronous** and all previous considerations apply directly to them.
You Cannot Receive Synchronous Result From Asynchronous Function.
I hold this truth against all downvotes.

Comment: Not sure why this is downvoted, but I suspect it's because you said "cannot receive a synchronous result from an asynchronous function" and then recommend a user-implemented pattern that does just that.  Perhaps you meant there's no native function that does that?

Comment: @BotNet which of patterns I mentioned return **synchronous** result?

Comment: using callbacks is a form of synchronicity.  A succession of AJAX calls may fire off asynchronous functions, but if you latch into their callbacks, you're utilizing a measure of what makes the event synchronous.  *first this, then when it finishes, do this* (one happens before the other, the other waits for the first to finish - it's by loose definition of the word, synchronous)